# Capturing parameters from a POST request in Spock

Tags: haskell, haskell-wai, haskell-spock

In the documentation of Spock, here https://www.spock.li/2015/04/19/type-safe_routing.html, it only describes how to capture parameters from a get request. I need to capture ones from a post. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same  `param'` or `param` functions.
From the documentation :

> Read a request param. Spock looks POST variables first and then in GET
>   variable